# initexmf --register-root=/path followed by initexmf --update-fndb on Ubuntu 20.04 terminal on Windows 10 fails to register bib file

Tags: miktex, biber, texmf, texmf-local

I have installed MikTex for Ubuntu 20.04 on a Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 shell:

```
user@machine:/mnt/c/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/project$ sudo initexmf --register-root=/mnt/c/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/texmf
initexmf: security risk: running with elevated privileges
user@machine:/mnt/c/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/project$ sudo initexmf --update-fndb
initexmf: security risk: running with elevated privileges
user@machine:/mnt/c/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/project$ ls /mnt/c/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/texmf/bibtex/bib/
library.bib
user@machine:/mnt/c/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/project$ biber project-file
INFO - This is Biber 2.16
INFO - Logfile is 'project-file.blg'
INFO - Reading 'project-file.bcf'
INFO - Found 13 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'library.bib' for section 0
ERROR - Cannot find 'library.bib'!
INFO - ERRORS: 1
biber: major issue: So far, you have not checked for MiKTeX updates.
```

Comment: Does `kpsewhich library.bib` return the path of your `library.bib` or nothing at all?

Comment: `$ kpsewhich library.bib
kpsewhich: major issue: So far, you have not checked for MiKTeX updates.`  I have only command line no gui.  @moewe

Comment: That means it is not a Biber issue, but a `kpsewhich`/MikTeX problem.

Comment: @moewe I found this: `https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/724` and followed the instructions as well as using an elevated shell, but I still get the same error as well a `log4cxx` error.